# Картинка заслоняет уголки у блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сделал у текстового блока уголки с помощью двух прямоугольников псевдоклассов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При изменении `z-index` у изображения оно начинает закрывать уголки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Код:**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root{
    --corners-px: 5px;
    --negative-corners-px: -5px;
}

body{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #924a23;
}

.img_background{
    width:40%;
    height:40%;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;
    left: 60%;
}
.corners{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #FFD0BF;
    margin: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}


.corners::before{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #924a23;  /*#924a23*/
    top: var(--corners-px);
    left: var(--negative-corners-px);
}

.corners:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #924a23;  /*#924a23*/
    top: var(--negative-corners-px);
    left:var(--corners-px);
}

.text_box{
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img_background" id="books_img"><img src="books.png"></div>
        <div class="corners"><div class="text_box">КНИГИ</div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Цель:**
А хочется чтобы уголки были верхним слоем(при увеличении z-index простые прямоугольники начинают перекрывать текстовый блок), следующим текст, а внизу блок фото. Как-то так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как такое реализовать?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для уголков лучше сделать маленькие блоки и задать им бордер по нужным сторонам, все это выровнять и лучше задавать размеры в процентах или вьюпортах. Я так накидал, для наглядности.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url(https://icytales.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/6545528_pile-of-old-books-on-desk-scaled.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.corners1 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 10px;
}
.corners2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 10px;
}
.container {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="corners1"></div>
    <div class="text_box">КНИГИ</div>
    <div class="corners2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```